# jquery update breaks

Tags: jquery, onchange

jquery update breaks when jquery, itself update input value!!

i have some input boxes and i wrote some jquery functions like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#ind2').change( function() {
       $('#ind5').val( parseInt($('#ind2').val()) + parseInt($('#ind1').val())    );
 });
});
```

---

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#ind5').change( function() {
           $('#ind1').val( parseInt($('#ind7').val()) + parseInt($('#ind5').val())    );
     });
    });
```

when input "**ind2**" changes input "**ind5**" will change so i need second function " **$('#ind5').change**" call automatically !! but "**$('#ind5').change**" just calls when user change input "**ind5**" strightly!!

what must i do?!

Comment: @afane Why dont you try calling $('#ind5').change() inside the  $('#ind2') change event

Comment: @KamalDeepSingh: because it mades dynamically by a recersive function and i cant do that it is realy hard for manage!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trigger  the change on `#ind5` using `trigger`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#ind2').change( function() {
       $('#ind5').val( parseInt($('#ind2').val()) + parseInt($('#ind1').val())    );
       $("#ind5").trigger('change');
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well, not judging the functionallity of your script (which seems very flawd), you would need to check if the value is the combination of the others and vice verca;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#ind5').change( function() {
       if (this.value!==(parseInt($('#ind2').val()) + parseInt($('#ind1').val())){
           $('#ind1').val( parseInt($('#ind7').val()) + parseInt($('#ind5').val())    );
       }
 });
});
```